# Jug problem with 3 jugs [3, 4, 5]

Tags: calculation-puzzle, decanting-problems

How do you get 10 and 11 liters from 3, 4, and 5 liter jugs?

Answer (score 2):

If the question means the quantity should be held in the jugs without wasting any:

> **10 L**
>  Fill the **3**
>  Empty it into the 5
>  Fill the **3** again
>  Fill the **4**
>  Total = **10**
>  
>  **11 L**
>  Fill the **4**
>  Empty it into the 5
>  Fill the **4** again
>  Fill the **3**
>  Total = **11**

Answer (score 0):

10 liters is

> 2 5 liter jugs

11 liters is

> 2 3 liter jugs and a five liter jug